# Alias specific hostnames by regex to fully qualified domain name (FQDN)

Tags: domain-name-system, hostname, alias

Is there any way on linux to alias a group of hostnames (group specified by wildcards/regex) starting i.e c-* to fully qualified domain names

i.e

> c-hostname -> c-hostname.domain.com

Thank you,

J.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases in a DNS server - hosting your own DNS is not very complicated, just create a local zone & have your search suffix resolve against it with those hosts in it aliased to their actual domain names.

This may "break" TLS though. Certs need to match the name you are using to connect to the resource.